# Cannot send email with paramter(id) to my domain's email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, office365

I have a domain which I have purchased with Godaddy. I have setup Office 365 email with this domain so that my app or other people could send email by using this domain email.

Right now, I am able to send all email to this domain just fine. But when I try to test to put some parameter(id) onto the address, the email is failed to be sent. I need to be able to make this work as I need to use this domain email for my rails app.

This is example of email address with the id that i am trying to send to: `support+296@rentlord.info`

And this is the error that I received:

[image]

I have tried this with my gmail and gmail completely ignore the "+" sign and the parameter that I supplied and send/receive the email just fine. But when I tried it on my domain, it failed to be sent. Do I need to setup something?

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a Gmail feature and not something that works generally with emails. If you want more addresses you have to add them.

Comment: But it's not possible to add new email address as each id is unique and belong to post. I have seen many people doing this as part of their application and using the custom domain's email